# What are good document organization utilities?

Tags: software-rec, documents

I'm a graduate student and I have to deal with reading a lot of academic papers. I was wondering if there were any good utilities for linux for organizing documents (pdfs mostly) for reading.

Having utilities that are open-sourced would be a plus.

Comment: Not sure of your exact requirement. But you could look at some options in this question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/18495/which-pdf-viewer-would-you-recommend

Comment: [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) comes to mind. Having said that, no program is a substitute for having a well-curated and organized file hierarchy.

Comment: Right now, I'm going by directories, of course. It just would help to have the organization with a view of the current document.

Comment: Calibre will allow to tags documents which is a real improvement to hierarchical organization.

Comment: @Emmanuel, if you wish, a creative use of symlinks would yield similar results to tagging. :P

Comment: You might also want to look at Bibliography managers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33619/latex-and-bibliography-management-tools

Comment: @HalosGhost Yes you are right; I remember I sorted my mailling lists emails that way when I was using mh; I was also indexing with "glimpse" at that time (long time ago). So perhaps a hierarchic tree, with a good text indexer and some scripts will be sufficient :)

Comment: I use Google Drive for that. I allows to search, sharing and online reading. I failed to find anything more suitable for that.